# Access Datagridviewcolumn that is not in bound List

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a DatagridCheckBoxColumn that is not in the bound source, so I can select specific rows via gui. Then I want to iterate over the datagrid and call a stored procedure with each selected row.

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="G_DG_Data"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="1"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyGridData}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Mark" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Data}" Header="Data" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I tried to iterate over Datagrid.Items and Datagrid.Itemssource but I am unable to access the CheckBoxColumn values / the CheckBoxColumn.

Is this approach possible? Is there a better way?

EDIT:

I have this Property not in the ViewModel, because the ViewModel is EntityFramework with Database first and I fill the Datagrid directly from the Database, where the Property is useless.

```
private ObservableCollection<SDH_CRModul_Sniffer> myGridData;
public ObservableCollection<SDH_CRModul_Sniffer> MyGridData
{
    get { return myGridData; }
    set
    {
        if (myGridData == value) return;
        myGridData = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyGridData");
    }
}
```

Where SDH_CRModul_Sniffer is the Entity created from Entity Framework.

Comment: Since you apply functionality to the view state, e.g: call the stored procedure, why don't you just add it to your viewmodel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items in `Items` have no idea about any `CheckBox` in the UI. That's why you should bind it to a property of an item:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding YourProperty}" Header="Mark" />
```

If you don't, the state of a `CheckBox` may get lost or corrupted as you scroll through the rows because of the UI virtualization that is enabled by default.

The only way to get the value of the `CheckBox` if you don't bind is to iterate through the visual elements in the UI, and this won't work if some of them are virtualized away.

> I have this Property not in the ViewModel, because the ViewModel is EntityFramework with Database first and I fill the Datagrid directly from the Database, where the Property is useless.

Entity Framework generates partial classes so you could then create another partial class with the same name and add the property to this one. Or wrap the entity in a view model class and use this one in the `DataGrid` instead of the entity class.

Comment: This sounds horrible. I will create a local class that has the additional property. Thank you for explaining the actual cause!